# Make an image in Kivy exactly the same size as the widget bounding box

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm having trouble in Kivy setting an image size. I want to keep the aspect ratio fixed but I also want to position things precisely over the top of the image.
To do this, I make a RelativeLayout that has the same size and position as the image. However, when I check the size of the layout, it is always slightly larger than the displayed image. Making precise alignment very difficult. The [wiki](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=image#module-kivy.uix.image) mentions something like this:

> By default, the image is centered and fits inside the widget bounding box. If you don’t want that, you can set allow_stretch to True and keep_ratio to False.

They also include code if you want to make the image slightly larger than the containing widget:

```
<-FullImage>:
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: (1, 1, 1)
    Rectangle:
        texture: self.texture
        size: self.width + 20, self.height + 20
        pos: self.x - 10, self.y - 10
```

But nothing about making them exactly the same size!? Surely I should be able to dictate the containing widgets size so the aspect ratio etc. is exactly as required.

I have tried many things but whatever I try, I cannot get the outside edges of the displayed image and a layout to coincide.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I have discovered the problem, the images had a transparent border that I wasn't aware of (the images were passed on to me from elsewhere) I have removed this and it has solved the problem.